# Will not return false, or display the alert for function combine() when true. Does someone see a mistake I don't?

Tags: javascript, html, return

//  I apologize for giving the whole code, with omission of the urls, but my code will be returning false just fine, then the next time I try to add a new function, it will no longer return false, and upon removing the new function, it does not return to working again as it did before.  I have tried onsubmit=return and onclick=return both.

The other issue is for function combine() in my code.  It doesn't ever seem to work, and I have tried numerous different methods.  I have tried just alerting with "Test", and the alert doesn't even work.

UPDATED:  Now we have it returning false properly for invoices not matching, with alert.  It also gives alert for Emails not matching, however it does not return false for emails not matching, and continues to the url.  I am showing no errors in the console now.  It also does correctly combine and alert to show the invoice and name together.

UPDATE:  Now have it working completely.  See my final comment below to see how I fixed this last issue.  Hope this helps someone!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- // working code except for combining the invoice with the name -->
<head>
  <title>INFORMATION FORM</title>
</head>

<!-- // This code compares two fields in a form and submit it -->
<!-- // if they're the same, or not if they're different. -->
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkInvoice(theform) {
    if (theform.invoice1.value != theform.invoice2.value)
    {
        alert("The INVOICE numbers do not match, please review for mistakes to assure your account gets credited.");
        return false;

} else {checkEmail(theform);
    }
}

function checkEmail(theform) {
    if (theform.EMAIL_1.value != theform.Email.value)
    {
        alert("The EMAIL addresses you provided do not match.  Please correct the EMAIL address and try again.");
        return false;


} else {

<!-- // This code combines two fields into the CustRefID-->
function combine()
{
var y=document.getElementById("invoice2").value;
var x=document.getElementById("FName").value;
var InvoiceName = y+""+x;
document.getElementById("CustRefID").value = InvoiceName;
alert(document.getElementById("CustRefID").value);
}
        combine();  <!--// this calls the combine function when the email addresses match-->              
        return true;
            }
}







</script>





<form name=theform action= "https://hos###/Index" method ="POST" target="_blank" onsubmit="return checkInvoice(this);"  >
<input type="hidden" name="HostedKey" id="HostedKey" value="####" />
<input type="hidden" name="Gateway_ID" id="Gateway_ID" value="#####" />
<input type="hidden" name="IndustryCode" id="IndustryCode" value="2" />
<!-- the next line blank value tells the hosted page to allow the customer to use credit cards as the only allowed payment type. -->
<!-- If you want to only allow more than credit cards, replace “CC” with “” for the value  -->
<input type="hidden" name="PaymentType" id="PaymentType" value="CC" />
<!-- the next line allows the hosted page to capture some perhaps useful info to identify the payment.  -->
<strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">INVOICE</span></strong> Number: <input type="text" name="invoice1" required id="invoice1" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" />
<br>
Please Confirm your <strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">INVOICE</span></strong> number: <input type="text" name="invoice2" required id="invoice2" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" />
<p>
Patient Full Name (as it appears on your paper bill): <input type="text" name="FName" id="FName" required value="" size="40" maxlength="40" />
<p>
PHONE (###-###-####): <input type="text" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" name="PhoneNumber" required id="PhoneNumber" value="" />
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="Amount" id="Amount" value="" />
<!-- the next line’s N value tells the hosted page to not display recurring payment fields  -->
<input type="hidden" name="RecurringType" id="RecurringType" value="N" />
<input type="hidden" name="RecurringAmount" id="RecurringAmount" value="" />
<!-- the next line defines where users are directed after a successful purchase. It is suggested you create a simple Thankyou page for the site. -->
<input type="hidden" name="RURL" id="RURL" value="http://www.######.com/thankyou/"  />
<!-- the next line defines where users are directed after they hit the Cancel button on the TXP Hosted page  -->
<input type="hidden" name="CURL" id="CURL" value="http://www.########.com/cancelled/" />
<!-- If AVSRequired equals "Y", Address Line 1 and ZIP Code become required fields on the hosted page  -->
<input type="hidden" name="AVSRequired" id="AVSRequired" value="Y"/>
<!-- If CVV2Required is set to "Y", than CVV2 becomes a required field on the hosted page  -->
<input type="hidden" name="CVV2Required" id="CVV2Required" value="Y"/>
<!-- If EmailRequired is set to "Y", then Email becomes a required field on the hosted page  -->
<input type="hidden" name="EmailRequired" id="EmailRequired" value="Y"/>
<!-- the next line defines enables/disables the ability to receive response data in an POST format. When set to N, no response data is returned to the RURL -->
<input type="hidden" name="PostRspMsg" id="PostRspMsg" value="N"/>
<!-- You can also use a graphic for the button to improve the appearance -->




<p> Enter Your Email Address:<br>
<input type="TEXT" name="EMAIL_1" value="" id=EMAIL_1 required size="40" maxlength="40"> 
<br>
Please Confirm Your Email Address:
<br>
<input type="TEXT" name="Email" required  value= "" size="40" maxlength="40" /> 
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="CustRefID"  id="CustRefID" value="" />

<!-- the next line defines what text is on the button. Replace Submit Payment Now with whatever you desire -->
<p>
<input type="SUBMIT" name="Button" id="Button" value="Make Payment Now" ></p> 


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Open the browser's error console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look at the error message. You don't have an element with the id "FName" so trying to refer to it throws an error.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your help.  This newbie could use it.  I fixed the FName and added an id for it......id=FName.  Now, the error console is highlighting this: function checkInvoice(theform) {
    if (theform.invoice1.value != theform.invoice2.value)
    //Error console says cannot read property value of undefined.  I have it defined, so I thought.

Comment: Seems like the value is not being passed to the javascript for some reason, but it is all in the same body.  I am stumped.

Comment: `theform` refers to the submit button, not to the form. Don't use an `onclick` event on a submit button to catch form submission, it doesn't trigger when you press enter to submit etc. Move it to the form tag and make it an `onsubmit` event.

Comment: That's actually what I was doing before, funny thing, so I have put it back the way you suggested and having a little more progress now.  No errors anymore, and it does give alerts if the emails or invoice numbers don't match, but it still continues to open the url even if the emails don't match.  It does return false for the invoices not matching.  I am wondering if I can't return false in a function I am calling, after already returning true in the function calling the next function.

Comment: I was mistaken, and apparently already was thinking that through when I wrote it, as I am not returning true in the first function, I am allowing the check Email function to make that decision.

Comment: I updated the above code to what we have discussed.

Comment: Getting there.  Will update code as things get better.  Currently everything works perfectly except for when emails don't match, it does not return false.

Comment: I separated the checkEmail and checkInvoice functions, and instead:  onsubmit="return checkInvoice(this)&&checkEmail(this);"   Works like a charm now.  Thank you for the help in pointing out some newbie errors and helping me use some obvious tools.  Have a great weekend.